# Authorization OAuth 1.0 works with Postman, fails via Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth, cryptography, postman

I am trying to authorize my application with [HERE, the open API for maps](https://developer.here.com/) and following their instructions [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html) I am able to retrieve an `accessToken`. However, when I try to sign the request using Node.js' `crypto`, the signature I am getting is different than the one provided by Postman.

Here is the HTTP code snippet from Postman:

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: account.api.here.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="apiKey",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
    oauth_timestamp="1591720243",
    oauth_nonce="X6Ukw2TWTBp",
    oauth_version="1.0",
    oauth_signature="rqXoIM8YOYpsLjcWZ5Yau15%2BDIwPHhj%2B7jk8xyAfpU4%3D"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Here is my Node.js code:

```
crypto = require('crypto'),
apiKey = 'apiKey',
url = 'https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token',
sharedSecret = 'sharedSecret'

var reqObj = {
    oauth_consumer_key: apiKey,
    oauth_nonce: "X6Ukw2TWTBp",
    oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA256",
    oauth_timestamp: "1591720243",
    oauth_version: "1.0"
};

var paramsStr = '';
for (var i in reqObj) {
  paramsStr += "&" + i + "=" + reqObj[i];
}

// had an extra '&' at the front
paramsStr = paramsStr.substr(1);

var sigBaseStr = "POST&" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(paramsStr);

// no access token but we still have to append '&' according to the instructions
sharedSecret += "&";

var hashedBaseStr  = crypto.createHmac('sha256', sharedSecret).update(sigBaseStr).digest('base64');
console.log(encodeURIComponent(hashedBaseStr));
```

The above code ouputs the following: `fWmRNPpjrbBkVBQiS8DhjTo6G%2B5Tpeb6PZAxNVo7sWc%3D`. While from Postman's header, you can see that the signature is `rqXoIM8YOYpsLjcWZ5Yau15%2BDIwPHhj%2B7jk8xyAfpU4%3D`.

I even followed the tutorial on [this page](http://lti.tools/oauth/), but it is returning the exact same signature as my code, which does not translate into a valid request.

Can someone please point me to where the issue is in my code? I have already checked that the `sigBaseStr` follows the requests listed in the OAuth 1.0 specs, so I am not sure what else might be the issue.

To sumarize, I want **my code** to output `rqXoIM8YOYpsLjcWZ5Yau15%2BDIwPHhj%2B7jk8xyAfpU4%3D`.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the issue was.

According to the example listed [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-aaa-javasdk-or-3rd-party-libraries.html), the `grant_type=client_credentials` pair must also be a part of the `reqObj`.

Once I added it, I was able to match Postman's and my code's signatures.

Here is the correct code:

```
crypto = require('crypto'),
apiKey = 'apiKey',
url = 'https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token',
sharedSecret = 'sharedSecret'

var reqObj = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials", // <- new line
    oauth_consumer_key: apiKey,
    oauth_nonce: "X6Ukw2TWTBp",
    oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA256",
    oauth_timestamp: "1591720243",
    oauth_version: "1.0"
};

var paramsStr = '';
for (var i in reqObj) {
  paramsStr += "&" + i + "=" + reqObj[i];
}

// had an extra '&' at the front
paramsStr = paramsStr.substr(1);

var sigBaseStr = "POST&" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&" + encodeURIComponent(paramsStr);

// no access token but we still have to append '&' according to the instructions
sharedSecret += "&";

var hashedBaseStr  = crypto.createHmac('sha256', sharedSecret).update(sigBaseStr).digest('base64');
console.log(encodeURIComponent(hashedBaseStr));
```